# Fittig N-D periodic functions

Tags: fourier-series, approximation, wavelets

Besides fourier series, are there any stable way to fit N-D nonlinear functions that demonstrate some degree of periodicity, sigmoid neural networks works poorly in this domain.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid Fourier?

Comment: @icurays1 Beause fourier series work not so well so I want to try some alternatives, well, if there are any.